# Java String... question regarding multiple inputs for a method

Tags: java, string, dynamicparameters

is it possible to create a class and have a String ... attribute that takes as many or as little strings as you put?
example:
please excuse my rough pseudocode, this is for java.

```
//this is the method:
public void getXXXX(String ...) {
//random code executes in a loop with as many as strings that are inputted
}

//this code calls it
getXXXX("Benjamin","Jordan","Steve")
getXXXX("Pengu","No")
getXXXX("hi")
```

Comment: Search for java varargs. It’s pretty much exactly your pseudocode, except you give the argument a name and it will be an array.

Comment: Any reason you're not using a container like ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you entered will more or less work, you just need a parameter name after your type.

```
class StringDecorator {
    public static String join(final String... strings) {
        final var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (final var string : strings) {
            builder.append(string);
        }
    
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Then invoke this somewhere

```
StringDecorator.join("Hello, ", "World!"); // "Hello, World!"
```